# How to repartition disk to use non-allocated space?

Tags: partition, gparted

This is how my hard drive (where I have Xubuntu 12.10) is formatted currently, based on a recent GParted screenshot:

[image: GParted Screenshot]

I want to expand sda6 (4) to take up the free 11.72 GiB unallocated space. But I can't do it. This is what I did and gathered so far:

- I can't add another primary partition as I have 4 already. I didn't know that prior to starting up GParted and right-clicking the unallocated 11.72 GiB space. :/
- /dev/sda5 is swap.
- /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3 are Windows partitions and need to remain as they are.

I am a bit clueless on how to enhance /sda6 now, I have definitely not enough basic knowledge on how to proceed. :( I don't even know if I have to keep the [swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_space) partition but that thought is moot anyway as I can't create another primary partition. Help! I'd appreciate it a lot. :)

I'd even be willing a tutorial which could help me get forward via the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't explicitly say what you want to do, but I guess you want to use that spare 11GB of space to expand /dev/sda6. **You won't be able to do this while you are running Linux from the sda6 partition - the usual solution is to use a LiveCD, perhaps SystemRescueCD, to run GParted.**

The best way to do this is:

- Resize/Move your extended partition, sda4, so that it includes that 11GB of space
- Move sda5 so that it comes before the free space in the extended partition (i.e. by changing the "free space preceding" value in the Move window to 0)
- Resize sda6 so that it uses up all the free space.

Alternatively:

- Resize/Move your extended partition, sda4, so that it includes that 11GB of space
- Create a new logical partition, sda7, using that 11GB of space, and mount that as the folder where you need most space (likely as /home).

Comment: Your guess is right. Sorry I thought that was clear from my post but re-reading you are right. I can't do anything to neither sda4 nor sda6, every entry in the context menu is greyed out. Ok, technically speaking I could still click on "Manage Flags" and "Information" but I can't resize/move them.

Comment: My best guess is that you're trying to do this from the Linux instance running on /dev/sda6, which won't work - you can't move these things around the disk while they're in use. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Holy crap. The machine is now unbootable as it enter the grub rescue mode. What now?

Comment: That depends on exactly what you did in GParted and what the final disk layout was: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#grub_rescue.3E-1 may prove helpful.

Comment: I know its too late to comment now but still I would like to do. You moved the whole linux partition and so it failed to boot. You might have used some way to recover but when I face any booting issue I boot from my live Ubuntu 12.10 CD and run command to re-install GRUB (boot-loader).